# JSON array get likes for php

Tags: php, json, instagram

JSON array Output:

```
array(3) {
["pagination"]=>
array(0) {
}
["meta"]=>
array(1) {
["code"]=>
int(200)
}
["data"]=>
array(9) {
[0]=>              // for first image
array(15) {
  ["attribution"]=>
  NULL
  ["tags"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(17) "düğündernekvol"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "brother"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "suit"
  }
  ["likes"]=>        //total likes count for instagram
  array(1) {
    ["count"]=>
    int(40)
  }
```

---

PHP Code

```
if(isset($json_data)){
$search_response = curlRequest("get", "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token={$json_data['access_token']}");
$search_response = json_decode($search_response, true);
echo "<pre>";

var_dump($search_response);
echo "</pre>";
```

I want to get from JSON output only 'likes'  "for example: likes : 40"

I'm trying to list the number of picture like

(I am getting my instagram account  photos information)

Comment: `echo $search_response['data'][0]['likes']`.

Comment: Output : Array ----->
"just writes"

Comment: I wrote    echo $search_response['data'][0]['likes']['count'];  it's okey :)